# Store PhoneInput and Select value in DynamoDB AWS ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I need to store a `<PhoneInput>` phone number value and a `<Select>` tag country input in DynamoDB.  When I try to submit, its not getting reflected in my db. So what changes do I have to make.
I used: `npm react-phone-number-input` and `npm react-select-country-list`.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<PhoneInput 
     className="phone"
     placeholder="Enter phone number"
     value={value}
     onChange={setValue} name="phonenumber" />
```

```html
<Select className="react-select-country-list" options={options}
    name="country" value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
```

```js
 async function addContact() {
    const data = {
        body: {
            first_name: formState.first_name,
            last_name: formState.last_name,
            email: formState.email,
            phonenumber: formState.phonenumber,
            help: formState.help,
            country: formState.country,
            message: formState.message
          

        }
    }
        console.log(data);
        const apiData = await API.post('contact', '/contacts', data);
        console.log({ apiData };
        alert('Mail sent');
};
```

Comment: Sounds like your API endpoint isn't working as expected. Can you post the API code?

Comment: but input tags are getting stored in my db, ```<input name="first_name" onChange={e => updateFormState('first_name', e.target.value)} type="text" required className="form-control" />```,   only PhoneInput and Select is not getting stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the onChange =  onChange={x => updateFormState('phonenumber', x)}